# Link stylesheet with media query to React component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In an html file it is possible to link stylesheets like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 768px)" href="small.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1150px)" href="big.css">
```

In a JSX file you can only import css files like: `import "./big.css"`

How can I conditionally import CSS files into a React component based off the screen size?

Comment: The answer will depend upon how you are building/bundling your app.  React/JSX itself has no support for "importing css files".

Comment: You could maybe try it with css modules - https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules , the conditional import part would depend on how you are bundling though. alternatively you could just use 1 stylesheet with media queries ...

Comment: I'm using webpack and have a css loader which just bundles every css file in the app. Then I access a bundled css file like this: import "./example.css"

Answer (score 0):

you can use require and conditionally import modules, like below example:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
  require('./index.css')
}
```

if you prefer using ES6 `import`, it doesn't work out of the box, you need to configure it. Check out babel plugin dynamic imports [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/)

`Note: the above example works after a reload if you are dynamically changing screen size in browser but, if you initially start with a smaller screen size, the css will load. if you need to dynamically re-render your component when the user or developer resizes the browser window, then implement that logic for re-rendering your component based on screen size`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :
Whenever **window loads** or **screen size is changed** the function will execute and you can customise it according to your need .

```
let importCSS = function(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
       require('./index.css')
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load",importCSS);
window.addEventListener("resize", importCSS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are ok, but considering you need it to be rendered dynamically, this wouldn't work because you are not actually getting the window values when it changes.

I'll suggest doing the following:
You can use modules, in that way you can "recreate" how mediaqueries work
like so: `[name].module.css`

JSX:

```
 import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
   import homeStyles from "../public/Home.module.css"

export default function App() {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
       setValue(window.innerWidth)
     })
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={
        value < 650 ? homeStyles.colorOne : homeStyles.colorTwo
      }>
        The value is
        {
          value
        }
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
 .colorOne {
  color: blue;
}


.colorTwo {
  color: red;
}
```

That way, you can kinda recreate what a media query is, using the code I wrote above and the window.innerWidth value, eg:

This works exactly how a media query will work, yeah, it's not the same but if you really have to do it, you can try this out.